# How stop a div from scroll to bottom when user scroll up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a chat box that, when user messages load, it will scroll to the bottom of the div, but the problem now is that it keeps on scrolling to bottom even after the first scroll and when the user tries to scroll up to read the previous message, it will scroll down again, but I don't like it, because it so inconvenience for my clients.
This is my code for scroll one my Dom loads

load_id is unique id for each div create with PHP

```
 $("#"+load_id)[0].scrollHeight + $("#"+load_id)[0].scrollHeight + $("#"+load_id)[0].clientHeight + $("#"+load_id)[0].clientHeight;
```

**My HTML**

```
<div class='unique-chat-c' id='unique-chat-c"+c_by+"-"+c_to+"-"+b_id+"-"+bs+"'>
  <input type='hidden' id='unique-chat-up-status"+c_id+"-"+bs+"' value='0'>
  <div class='i-unique-chat-c'><div class='unique-cat-top'>
    <div class='unique-cat-top-l'>
      <img src='"+u_url+"' class='user-me-img'> 
      <img src='"+url+"' class='end-user-img'></div>
      <div class='unique-cat-top-r'>
        <div class='unique-cat-top-r-more'>
          <ul><li class='disconnect-buiz'>disconnect<input type='hidden' value='"+c_id+"'></li><li>view buiz</li>
          </ul>  </div>
           <i class='fa fa-gear'></i> <i class='fa fa-close'></i>
         </div></div>

         <div class='clear'></div>

         <div class='unique-cat-center' > 

        </div>

       </div></div>
```

Css for the center div that loads chat

```
.unique-cat-center{
    height:250px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position:relative;
    background:#e2e5e0;
}
```

Comment: just make the `position:fixed;` and `bottom:0`

Comment: I tried It but  still doing same thing

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: check my code please

Comment: Sorry i figure out the problem is from my chat update that calls every 5 seconds and scroll to down